# Drag & drop hints are lost in Telerik's RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX

Tags: drag-and-drop, tree, telerik, hint

I have a Telerik tree and drag & drop node move is in action. But then I applied a theme (bought from somewhere) to the overall design of my site, and now, the hint are gone. 
When you drag a node, some horizontal hint lines appear, so that you can understand that if you release your node (drop it) where it would be dropped.

Comment: Specifying what platform you are using (ASP.NET AJAX / MVC) would help. Otherwise - the theme most definitely overrides some of the embedded treeview styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something's `z-index` property is messing up with Telerik's RadTree. It's all `z-index` stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following CSS to the page. It will force the styles upon the TreeView drop hint.

```
.rtDropAbove, .rtDropBelow {
    border: 1px dotted black !important;
    font-size: 3px !important;
    height: 3px !important;
    line-height: 3px !important;
    margin-top: -1px !important;
}

.rtDropAbove {
    border-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.rtDropBelow {
    border-top: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: didn't help, but really thanks for your answer. The problem was, when z-index of another applied style which was hiding the hovered element. Telerik uses z-index of 0 or 1 for drag & drop hint lines.